# Pycharm/Python OpenCV and CV2 install error

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I've been trying to install both OpenCV and cv2 from both Pycharm and from the terminal as suggested using:

```
pip install --user opencv
pip install --user cv2
```

but I'm getting the following error for them:

```
Collecting opencv
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv
```

and

```
Collecting cv2
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cv2
```

How can I fix these and install the packages properly? I'm using python 3.4.

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu try `sudo apt-get install python3-opencv`

Answer (score 316):

You are getting those errors because `opencv` and `cv2` are not the python package names.

These are both included as part of the `opencv-python` package available to install from pip.

If you are using python 2 you can install with pip:

```
 pip install opencv-python
```

Or use the equivilent for python 3:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

After running the appropriate pip command your package should be available to use from python.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39308557/281545 below too - why was flagged as a no answer in the review is beyond me

Comment: Note that depending on how your python installations are set-up `pip install package-name` might install it for python3,  and you'd need to do `pip2` to get installed for python 2.x. `pip` should match whatever `python` does from the command line.

Comment: Note if you are installing it in Pycharm Settings: Project <name>=>python Interpreter adding it with the "+", the package name on the list to search for is not "cv2" but opencv-python

Answer (score 30):

This the correct command that you need to install opencv

```
pip install opencv-python
```

if you get any error when you are trying to install the "opencv-python" package in pycharm, make sure that you have added your python path to '**System Variables**' section of Environment variables in Windows.
And also check whether you have configured a valid interpreter for your project

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same problem. One issue might be OpenCV is created for Python 2.7, not 3 (not all python 2.7 libraries will work in python 3 or greater). I also don't believe you can download OpenCV directly through PyCharm's package installer. I have found luck following the instructions: [OpenCV Python](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html#install-opencv-python-in-windows). Specifically:

1. Downloading and installing OpenCV from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/)
2. Copying the cv2.pyd file from the download (opencv\build\python\2.7\x64) into Python's site-packages folder (something like: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages)
3. In PyCharm, open the python Console (Tools>Python Console) and type:`import cv2`, and assuming no errors `print cv2.__version__`

Alternatively, I have had luck using this package [opencv-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python), which you can straightforwardly install using pip with `pip install opencv-python`

Good luck!

Answer (score 10):

```
python3.6 -m pip install opencv-python
```

will install cv2 in python3.6 branch

Answer (score 10):

On Windows:

```
!pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: add an explanation to the answer

Answer (score 8):

**Keep it simple and just run.**

```
pip install opencv-python
```

This is the simplest way of installing opencv.
If you still face issue, create a **virtual environment** and try installing opencv.

Comment: Don't think it's a good idea to sudo install while in venv.

Comment: shouldn't you never use sudo when installing python packages?

Answer (score 7):

Try this. I am using Jupyter notebook (OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Google Cloud Platform + on Windows). Executed following command in the Jupyter notebook to install opencv:

```
!pip install opencv-contrib-python    #working on both Windows and Ubuntu
```

After successful installation you will get following message:

```
Successfully installed opencv-contrib-python-4.1.0.25
```

Now restart the kernel and try to import opencv as:

```
import cv2
```

The same command can be used to installed opencv on Windows as well.

**SOLUTION 2:** try following commands to install opencv:
For Ubuntu:
Run following command from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libsm6 libxrender1 libfontconfig1
```

Restart Jupyter notebook kernel and execute following command:

```
!pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

NOTE: You can run all the above commands from the terminal as well without using '!'.

Answer (score 4):

I rather use Virtualenv to install such packages rather than the entire system, saves time and effort rather than building from source.

I use [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

Windows user can download

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

https://pypi.org/project/virtualenvwrapper-win/

Linux [follow](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html?#basic-installation)

```
pip install opencv-python
```

[opencv-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)

If processing a video is required

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

[opencv-contrib-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/)

If you do not need GUI in Opencv

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless
```

[opencv-contrib-python-headless](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python-headless/)

Answer (score 2):

[here is a tutorial](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/09/17/install-opencv-3-with-python-3-on-windows/) that worked for me without any problem.

Copied from the site above the important part:

> Download the OpenCV version corresponding to your Python installation
>   from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv). In my case, I’ve used
>   opencv_python-3.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl.
>
> Now, open a cmd window like before. You can open this directly in your
>   Downloads folder if you SHIFT and right click inside it. The idea is
>   to open a cmd window where you’ve downloaded the above [...] file. Use
>   the [...] command to install [...] OpenCV:
>
> ```
> 1     pip install "opencv_python-3.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl"
> ```

Additional note: don't forget to change the name of the downloaded file in the command you use.
Apparently by installing opencv, you'll have access to cv2 too.

Answer (score 1):

Installing opencv is not that direct. 
You need to pre-install some packages first.

I would not recommend the unofficial package opencv-python. Does not work properly in macos and ubuntu (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843316/solved-how-to-include-libgtk2-0-dev-and-pkg-config-in-cmake-when-installing?noredirect=1#comment72858371_42843316)). No idea about windows.

There are many webs explaining how to install opencv and all required packages. 
For example [this one](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/).

The problem of trying to install opencv several times is that you need to uninstall completely before attempting again, or you might end having many errors.

Answer (score 1):

you must install opencv-python
`pip/pip3 install opencv-python`
if you try `import opencv-python`, receive error.
Fix this error, use the `import cv2`

Answer (score 1):

How about try some different mirrors?
If you are in China, I highly recommend you try:

```
sudo pip install --index https://pypi.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/simple/ opencv-contrib-python
```

If not, just replace the url address to some other mirrors you like!
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

this will help you

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

[this is the snippet of successful installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OloJh.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you still find any error to install open-cv in your mac, try this:

```
opencv-python==4.2.0.34
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here are the steps for Windows 10 users.

Open CMD: `win+r` then type `cmd`. Now,

1. Type `pip install virtualenv`
2. Create a Virtual Environment, Type `virtualenv testopencv`
3. Get Inside testopencv, Type  `cd testopencv`
4. Activate the Virtual Environment, Type  `.\Scripts\activate`
5. Now Install Opencv, Type  `pip install opencv-contrib-python --upgrade`
6. Let's test Opencv, Type `Python` then `import cv2` hit enter then type `print(cv2.__version__)` to check if its installed

Now, open a new cmd, `win + r then type cmd`, repeat step 6. If it gives you an error.

Go inside the `testopencv` folder, inside `lib`. Copy everything, go to your python directory, inside `lib` folder paste it and skip that are already present.

Again open a new cmd, repeat `Step 6`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In win, download the py based latest numpy and Opencv from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and pip install its source in cmd. Later copy site-package folder from main py lib to venv lib.

Answer (score 0):

In jetso nano this work for me.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/JetsonHacksNano/buildOpenCV
$ cd buildOpenCV
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was facing this issue I used to install OpenCV in pycharm installed package panel where we can find under the settings tab. Search "OpenCV-python" and install it in the installed package panel of right interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

First step:

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

Second step:

```
pip install numpy
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

First run from **cmd**

```
pip --version
```

to make sure that you have the updated version installed.

Then run

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through with this link: https://learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi/

you can install OpenCV perfectly with out any error. but the problem was it will take lot of time to install.

I had used pi3 model B+ with 32GB class10 SD card for me it took more than 12 hours for complete installation.