# Unable to download/install packages with pip

Tags: python, pip

Whenever I input pip install opencv-python or any other package, it gives this error -

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))':
 /simple/opencv-python/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))':
 /simple/opencv-python/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))':
 /simple/opencv-python/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))':
 /simple/opencv-python/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))':
 /simple/opencv-python/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/opencv-python/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/opencv
-python/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

This seems like a problem with the internet connection, but it is perfectly fine.

Comment: `pip install opencv-python`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37776228/pycharm-python-opencv-and-cv2-install-error

Comment: I solved it, it was because of vpn