# No module named 'cv2' as Rasberry Pie

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, tensorflow-lite

I follow this URL read.md
(https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Lite-Object-Detection-on-Android-and-Raspberry-Pi/blob/master/Raspberry_Pi_Guide.md)

But,I encounter error.

```py
python3 TFLite_detection_webcam.py --modeldir=Sample_TFLite_model
```

error below

```py
no module named cv2
```

I only engaged in readmd.So, opencv include pip list.
opencv_version:3.4.6.27
python_version:3.7.0

Could you tell me what is wrong
Thank you.

Comment: Can you give us the result of `python3 -m pip freeze` please? Often pip command is linked to another python script.

Comment: follow:backports.entry-points-selectable==1.1.0
distlib==0.3.3
filelock==3.3.1
importlib-metadata==4.8.1
opencv-python==4.5.3.56
platformdirs==2.4.0
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
virtualenv==20.8.1
zipp==3.6.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37776228/pycharm-python-opencv-and-cv2-install-error

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment answer, you don t have pip linked to your python3.
Test to do this:

```
python3 -m pip install cv2
```

Then retry the command

```
python3 TFLite_detection_webcam.py --modeldir=Sample_TFLite_model
```

Comment: I tried this morning. but, this error occoured 'ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cv2

Comment: and another error below,'  File "TFLite_detection_webcam.py", line 19, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Comment: This is another error, please update your question now. Try to install numpy using same command